# Fullscreen button on keypress escape button state won't change to off

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, button, escaping

enter code here

```js
function fullscreen() {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
        (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
            
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
            
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', FSHandler);
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', FSHandler);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', FSHandler);
document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', FSHandler);

function FSHandler() {
    // FS = FullScreen
    if (!document.fullscreenElement 
    && !document.webkitIsFullScreen 
    && !document.mozFullScreen 
    && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
    
        document.getElementById("myonoffswitch ").checked = false;
        
    } else {
        
        document.getElementById("myonoffswitch ").checked = true;
    }
}
```

```css
.myonoffswitch {
  --color-invert: rgba(0,255,0,.5);
  --width: 150px;
  --height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  transform: scale(0.33);
  transform-origin: 33% 0;
}
.myonoffswitch .button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(55,55,55,0.77);
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.myonoffswitch .button:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, var(--color-invert), transparent);
  filter: blur(20px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease, transform 1s ease;
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.myonoffswitch .button .power-on,
.myonoffswitch .button .power-off {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  fill: none;
  stroke: var(--color-invert);
  stroke-width: 8px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
.myonoffswitch .button .power-on .line,
.myonoffswitch .button .power-off .line {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.myonoffswitch .button .power-on .circle,
.myonoffswitch .button .power-off .circle {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transform: rotate(-58deg);
  transform-origin: center 80px;
  stroke-dasharray: 220;
  stroke-dashoffset: 40;
}
.myonoffswitch .button .power-on {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
}
.myonoffswitch .button .power-on .line {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 1s;
}
.myonoffswitch .button .power-on .circle {
  opacity: 1;
  stroke-dashoffset: 220;
  transition: transform 0s ease, stroke-dashoffset 1s ease 0s;
}
.myonoffswitch input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}
.myonoffswitch input:checked + .button:after {
  opacity: 0.15;
  transform: scale(2) perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
}
.myonoffswitch input:checked + .button .power-on,
.myonoffswitch input:checked + .button .power-off {
  -webkit-animation: click-animation 0.3s ease forwards;
          animation: click-animation 0.3s ease forwards;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.myonoffswitch input:checked + .button .power-on .line,
.myonoffswitch input:checked + .button .power-off .line {
  -webkit-animation: line-animation 0.8s ease-in forwards;
          animation: line-animation 0.8s ease-in forwards;
}
.myonoffswitch input:checked + .button .power-on .circle,
.myonoffswitch input:checked + .button .power-off .circle {
  transform: rotate(302deg);
}
.myonoffswitch input:checked + .button .power-on .line {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.05s ease-in 0.55s;
}
.myonoffswitch input:checked + .button .power-on .circle {
  transform: rotate(302deg);
  stroke-dashoffset: 40;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease 0.2s, stroke-dashoffset 0.4s ease 0.2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes line-animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-25px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-25px);
  }
  85% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes line-animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-25px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-25px);
  }
  85% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes click-animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes click-animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
}
```

```html
<div id="myonoffswitch" name="myonoffswitch" style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:-33px;z-index:101010;" title="ON/OFF Fullscreen" class="myonoffswitch">
  <input onclick="fullscreen()" type="checkbox" />
  <div  class="button">
    <svg id="power-off" class="power-off">
      <use xlink:href="#line" class="line" />
      <use xlink:href="#circle" class="circle" />
    </svg>
    <svg id="power-on" class="power-on">
      <use xlink:href="#line" class="line" />
      <use xlink:href="#circle" class="circle" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- SVG -->
<svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <symbol xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150" id="line">
    <line x1="75" y1="34" x2="75" y2="58"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150" id="circle">
    <circle cx="75" cy="80" r="35"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

I found this fullscreen javascript on internet and I just can't "tweak it".
Svg button won't turn to off state if I hit escape button. When key escape is pressed I'd like to achieve that svg button turns to off state. I added an event listener at the end of javascript code still off state is not working...

The site is on this addres
https://www.forster.si/Titan/index.html

Comment: Yes I tried that too. Still no solution to the problem. Thank you for noticing my question...